# Methods for estimating the future evolution of these graphs

Tags: predictive-models

A friend and I were looking at the following graphs and discussing their possible future evolution:

[image]

The blue graph is inflation while the orange one is interest rate. Neither of us is particularly well versed in statistics (or economics..) and we were wondering which mathematical/statistical methods are at our disposal for estimating the evolution of these graphs.

Assuming we do not care about the economic factors in play but focused solely on the mathematical side, what models could we build to estimating the orange and/or blue graphs (for example over the next year) and how would they use the existing data ?  We make the implicit assumption that the graph will behave in a "similar" way as it did in the past, for some definition of similar - this may be wrong economically, but we're mainly interested in the mathematical side of it.

For example, two ideas we came up with - and please forgive me in advance if these are in some way crooked, we are but two amateurs:

1. divide the existing values into "buckets" (e.g. round each point on the graph to the nearest ~0.1), count the number of occurrences of each value, then use these as the probabilities of future values in a monte carlo simulation.
2. use an nth-order markov chain to try to take into account how likely it is for either graph to go up or down (this is a vague idea but we think it might work), where the states are the same buckets as in (1). With a regular markov chain we'd have to encode the probabilities into each state irrespective of how we got there, but with a higher order markov chain we could take into account if the previous state was higher or lower, albeit rather locally.

We don't need a full analysis, a name of the method and a brief sketch of how it would apply would be great. This is primarily for fun.

Thank you in advance for any answers or suggestions!